# React / Next.js Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, constants, jsx

I just started with React and dont get it, why the following Error message comes up:

> Server Error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside
> of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

It happend after adding the following component:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Popover, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

const navigation = [
  { name: "Product", href: "#" },
  { name: "Features", href: "#" },
  { name: "Marketplace", href: "#" },
  { name: "Company", href: "#" },
];

const HeroImage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative bg-gray-50 overflow-hidden">
      <div
        className="hidden sm:block sm:absolute sm:inset-y-0 sm:h-full sm:w-full"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="relative h-full max-w-7xl mx-auto">
          <svg
            className="absolute right-full transform translate-y-1/4 translate-x-1/4 lg:translate-x-1/2"
            width={404}
            height={784}
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 404 784"
          >
            <defs>
              <pattern
                id="f210dbf6-a58d-4871-961e-36d5016a0f49"
                x={0}
                y={0}
                width={20}
                height={20}
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              >
                <rect
                  x={0}
                  y={0}
                  width={4}
                  height={4}
                  className="text-gray-200"
                  fill="currentColor"
                />
              </pattern>
            </defs>
            <rect
              width={404}
              height={784}
              fill="url(#f210dbf6-a58d-4871-961e-36d5016a0f49)"
            />
          </svg>
          <svg
            className="absolute left-full transform -translate-y-3/4 -translate-x-1/4 md:-translate-y-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2"
            width={404}
            height={784}
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 404 784"
          >
            <defs>
              <pattern
                id="5d0dd344-b041-4d26-bec4-8d33ea57ec9b"
                x={0}
                y={0}
                width={20}
                height={20}
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              >
                <rect
                  x={0}
                  y={0}
                  width={4}
                  height={4}
                  className="text-gray-200"
                  fill="currentColor"
                />
              </pattern>
            </defs>
            <rect
              width={404}
              height={784}
              fill="url(#5d0dd344-b041-4d26-bec4-8d33ea57ec9b)"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="relative pt-6 pb-16 sm:pb-24">
        <Popover>
          <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
            <nav
              className="relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10 md:justify-center"
              aria-label="Global"
            >
              <div className="flex items-center flex-1 md:absolute md:inset-y-0 md:left-0">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full md:w-auto">
                  <a href="#">
                    <span className="sr-only">Workflow</span>
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </a>
                  <div className="-mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                    <Popover.Button className="bg-gray-50 rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                      <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                      <MenuIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </Popover.Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:flex md:space-x-10">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <a
                    key={item.name}
                    href={item.href}
                    className="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:absolute md:flex md:items-center md:justify-end md:inset-y-0 md:right-0">
                <span className="inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-600 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50"
                  >
                    Log in
                  </a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            enter="duration-150 ease-out"
            enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
            enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave="duration-100 ease-in"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
          >
            <Popover.Panel
              focus
              className="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden"
            >
              <div className="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
                <div className="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-auto"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="-mr-2">
                    <Popover.Button className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                      <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                      <XIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </Popover.Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
                  {navigation.map((item) => (
                    <a
                      key={item.name}
                      href={item.href}
                      className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </div>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-center font-medium text-indigo-600 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100"
                >
                  Log in
                </a>
              </div>
            </Popover.Panel>
          </Transition>
        </Popover>

        <main className="mt-16 mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:mt-24">
          <div className="text-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl">
              <span className="block xl:inline">Data to enrich your</span>{" "}
              <span className="block text-indigo-600 xl:inline">
                online business
              </span>
            </h1>
            <p className="mt-3 max-w-md mx-auto text-base text-gray-500 sm:text-lg md:mt-5 md:text-xl md:max-w-3xl">
              Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui
              lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat
              fugiat aliqua.
            </p>
            <div className="mt-5 max-w-md mx-auto sm:flex sm:justify-center md:mt-8">
              <div className="rounded-md shadow">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                >
                  Get started
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-3 rounded-md shadow sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-600 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                >
                  Live demo
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HeroImage;
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I Checked all three recommended steps. The first and third are fine, here are the results:

1. The versions of React and React DOM are not mismatching (react-dom@17.0.2 & react@17.0.2).
2. There is only one copy of React.

But I'm not sure about the second one "2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks", so I guess that one is the problem.

Comment: Is this component the only possible cause for the error? Are you calling any function that starts with `use` somewhere? I don't know how you checked for React copies, but take a look at  `npm ls react ` on the project hook to be sure

Comment: does it still crash after you remove <Transition> and <Popover>? if it does there is definitely issue with React's version(my guess would be that you have multiple instances of react/react-dom - even with the same version it will crash)